# Como validar que si un campo ya tiene 1 lo cambie a 0 y viceversa con Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Disculpen, tal vez sea muy simple y obvio mi problema, pero ya he tratado de solucionar e investigar una respuesta y nomás no doy.

Quisiera que cuando se agregue un valor en un Input Text marque 1 si esta en 0 o viceversa.

Este es mi formulario en HTML para enviar los datos. Los datos quiero capturarlos con un lector de código de barras, por eso el Input Text.

```
<form method="get">
        @csrf
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clave"  required>
            </div>                
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">Acceder</button></a>
</form>
```

Y en el controller, a pesar que ya he agregado y quitado muchas cosas, ahora lo deje simple para poder obtener su amable ayuda.

Controlador

```
public function acceso(Request $request, Locatarios $locatario)
{     
        DB::table('locatarios')->where('clave', request('clave'))->update(['enpuerto' => 1]);
    return view('Modulos.Entrada');
}
```

En Locatarios esta el campo **enpuerto** que quiero cambiar a 1 o 0 ó viceversa.

Es decir, si un locatario ingresa su clave se graba en la BD 1 (Entrada), si vuelve a ingresar su clave debe cambiar a 0 (salida).

Esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::get('Entrada', [LocatariosController::class, 'acceso']);
```

De esta manera si me funciona para cambiar 1.

Comment: A parte de que en tu formulario falta la ruta del action ¿cuál es el problema específico?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Gracias, Arcanis, checo cada uno.

Comment: Si no usas eloquent, puedes usar una raw expession para obtener la negación del valor actual de la columna y asignarlo en el update. Algo así `->update([ 'enpuerto’ => DB::raw('NOT enpuerto’) ])`